# path hints for a unique user

Tags: magento-1.7, template, layout

I know that in magento you can turn on path hints to find out which file you want to edit in order to edit the template, however, right now I work with a website that has a lot of users on the website all the time, so wondered if it is possible to turn on the path hints for admin only. Is this doable? 
Because it is no good to show customers the path hints as well as it is also not secure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, this is not doable, because the admin session is not the same session as the frontend session. Therefore you don't know whether you are logged in as admin or not.

## BUT

You have a field in the backend to enter your IP address, then all the developer features are only used, when the IP is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Fabian has the answer for you - however if this site is as heavily trafficked as you indicated you should not be editing it directly in the first place. Unless you have unknown superpowers, mistakes happen and you are sure you will get every edit correct the first time I would strongly advise to create a development copy of the site and work on that instead. Only once you are happy with the results roll them out to the live site.